# Outer horizon in the Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, kerr-metric

I have a question about the horizon of a Kerr black hole. Assuming that the metric has a coordinate singularity for $\Delta=0$, namely when $$r_\pm=GM\pm\sqrt{G^2M^2-a^2}$$
how can the outer horizon be non-spherically symmetric? I am confused because there is no $\theta$ dependence in the expression of $r_+$. According to this, shouldn't the horizon be at a distance $r_+$ from the centre of the black hole?
I am asking this because I have evaluated the length of the equator and this is indeed greater than the distance around the poles.